# Re-opening modal after closing one, laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.3

When I close my bootstrap modal, the modal opens again, then hide and the background stays darken. I am opening the modal on click on table tr. I also tried to force modal hide but it did not work. Please any help'll work.

```
<tr class="task-row task-row-{{$v_task->id}}" data-id="{{$v_task->id}}" data-target="#editTaskModal-{{$v_task->id}}">

<div id="editTaskModal-{{$v_task->id}}" class="modal fade editTaskModal" role="dialog" data-id="{{$v_task->id}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">{{$v_task->task_name}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label for="listNameInput" class="col-sm-2">Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="taskNameName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your task name..." id="taskNameInput-{{$v_task->id}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label for="listPriorityInput" class="col-sm-2">Priority:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="taskNamePriority" class="form-control" placeholder="Your priority..." id="taskPriorityInput-{{$v_task->id}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label for="listDeadlineInput" class="col-sm-2">Deadline:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="input-group datetimepicker2">
                                            <input type="datetime" name="taskNameDeadline" class="form-control deadlineInput" placeholder="Deadline..." id="taskDeadlineInput-{{$v_task->id}}">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon calendar-div">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success updateTaskModalBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button> or
                            <a data-dismiss="modal" href="" class="closeTaskModalLink"> Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you using an on click event function to close the modal?

Comment: I tried to use on click event as you can see here.
$('.editTaskModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('.editTaskModal').modal('hide');
   $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
   $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
 })

Comment: Ok, can you remove that and see what happens? I've included and explanation on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an onclick event which triggers when the `close` link has been click to close the modal.

Referring to this:

```
<a data-dismiss="modal" href="" class="closeTaskModalLink"> Close</a>
```

There's no need to do that since there's an attribute that would close the modal.

So I suggest change your code above and do below and see how it works.

```
<a data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
```

**Update**

Ok I see your JS code:

```
$('.editTaskModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {     
  $('.editTaskModal').modal('hide'); 
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); 
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); 
})
```

You should not include these, since what it would do is, if the modal is close/hidden it will hide the modal again. Which doesn't make sense since the modal is already close. That could be the reason why it's messing up the modal reveal/hide.

So remove that and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to do so but it unfortunatelly did not work. The modal hides but background stands darken. I noticed that every action I do with modal repeats, the modal repeats opening and closing, like I'd nest the event or something

Comment: @Epsilon47 Can you try removing `editTaskModal` as a class on your modal element. Probably something might be triggering the issue on the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the problem. I had had my modal in tr and I also had triggered the modal opening on tr click and when I was trying to dismiss the modal the event repeated opening.